# Does $E(\max(X,Y))$ equal to $\max(E(X),E(Y))$?

Tags: probability

You and a friend have placed a bet. The winner is chosen at random between the two of you. The winner gets a thousand dollars. The following random variables $X$ and $Y$ are defined:

- $X$: the amount that you win
- $Y$: the amount your friend wins

How would you prove that $E(\max(X,Y))$ does not equal to $\max(E(X),E(Y))$?

Comment: Actually, $E(\max(X,Y))=\max(E(X),E(Y))$ if and only if $X\geqslant Y$ almost surely or $Y\geqslant X$ almost surely.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\max{\{X,Y\}}=1000$ (certainly someone will win) while $E[X]=E[Y]<1000$ (the first equality due to symmetry and the inequality by intuition that you cannot win for sure).

Answer (score 0):

$\max(X,Y)$ is always $1000$, so it's expected value is $1000$.

Expected values of $X$ and $Y$ are both $500$ (if you and friend have both $50$% chance of winning) and $\max(500, 500)=500$.

If the chances are not equal, if you both have any non-zero probability of winning, then both $E[X], E[Y]$ are $<1000$ and so is their maximum.